# How to make a page within a page?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a website that needs an element added.
The current styles interfere with the element.
Is there any way no make a separate section in the page that has its own styles,
Like the way an iframe works?

Comment: So why not just use an iframe?

Comment: The element has moving parts

Comment: I don't understand what that means, let alone how it implies that an iframe is not suitable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sort of answered your own question in the question. The ideal way to do this is with an `<iframe>`.

If an `<iframe>` is not possible then you can manually 'scope' your CSS by prefixing all rules in your 'frame' with a certain ID and overriding your default styles:

```
.style1 { ... }
.style2 { ... }

#widget .style1 { ... }
#widget .style2 { ... }
```

Coming up in HTML5 you can actually scope CSS within a page. The following will only apply the styles to the inner `<div>`.

```
<div>
  <style scoped>
    div { color: red; }
  </style>
  <div>RED</div>
</div>
```

This isn't widely supported yet however.

Comment: so it can be done, but not very well

Comment: hmm interesting. i haven't seen this

Answer (score 1):

you can create a separate page that has its own css, and then embed it using iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You could enclose your secondary style in a `<div>` tag and override the rest of the code that way:

```
a {
    color:red
}

#newstyle a {
    color: blue
}
```

and the HTML of:

```
<a>This is red.</a> 
<div id="newstyle">
    <a>This is blue.</a>
</div>
```

However, there are probably better options.

Answer (score 0):

either use an iframe or use ajax to load the actual content of that page into a div on your page